# Correcting x axis in ggplot in function

Tags: r, ggplot2

This question is related to: [ggplot in function not working despite aes_string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778944/ggplot-in-function-not-working-despite-aes-string-in-r)

```
> dput(df1)
structure(list(firstvar = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), secondvar = c(25L, 
50L, 75L)), .Names = c("firstvar", "secondvar"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
> df1
  firstvar secondvar
1       a1        25
2       a2        50
3       a3        75

myplot = function(ddf){ 
    ggplot(ddf) +
        geom_bar(aes_string(1, names(ddf)[2], fill=names(ddf)[1]), stat="identity")+
        geom_text(aes_string(x=1, y=cumsum((ddf)[2]), label=names(ddf)[2]))
}

myplot(df1)
```

The plot is working but I want to have no text on x-axis (since 1 has been put just to have a point on x-axis; it does not mean anything in data). Putting any character, including "" blank character produces error or spoils the graph. How can I remove x-axis text here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove axis text with setting `axis.text.x` of `theme()` to `element_blank().`

```
myplot = function(ddf){ 
    ggplot(ddf) +
        geom_bar(aes_string(1, names(ddf)[2], fill=names(ddf)[1]), stat="identity")+
        geom_text(aes_string(x=1, y=cumsum((ddf)[2]), label=names(ddf)[2]))+
        theme(axis.text.x=element_blank())
     }

myplot(df1)
```

Comment: I needed axis.text.x=element_blank() . Thanks.